# Travis CI error on deploy to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, bundler, travis-ci, rspec3

Hello Guys I'm using for the first time Travis CI and when i'm getting an error for deploy. The test with Spec works fine but when I watch on Travis for deploy i'm getting some erros, it's some comment in production mode and I don't know what to do.
this is my app: https://github.com/romenigld/ticketee_two
And i'm getting this error on Travis:

```
Worker information
hostname: i-0542fe4-precise-production-2-worker-org-docker.travisci.net:2812671c-5374-45e4-bb33-10391842612d
version: v2.5.0 https://github.com/travis-ci/worker/tree/da3a43228dffc0fcca5a46569ca786b22991979f
instance: 0965c7d:travis:ruby
startup: 1.029777359s
system_info
Build system information
Build language: ruby
Build group: stable
Build dist: precise
Build id: 206202912
Job id: 206202913
travis-build version: c56b13141
Build image provisioning date and time
Thu Feb  5 15:09:33 UTC 2015
Operating System Details
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux Version
3.13.0-29-generic
Cookbooks Version
a68419e https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-cookbooks/tree/a68419e
GCC version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
LLVM version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Pre-installed Ruby versions
ruby-1.9.3-p551
Pre-installed Node.js versions
v0.10.36
Pre-installed Go versions
1.4.1
Redis version
redis-server 2.8.19
riak version
2.0.2
MongoDB version
MongoDB 2.4.12
CouchDB version
couchdb 1.6.1
Neo4j version
1.9.4
RabbitMQ Version
3.4.3
ElasticSearch version
1.4.0
Installed Sphinx versions
2.0.10
2.1.9
2.2.6
Default Sphinx version
2.2.6
Installed Firefox version
firefox 31.0esr
PhantomJS version
1.9.8
ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T17:29:23+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_76, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
fix.CVE-2015-7547
$ export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6-dev
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 270 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,840 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6-dev amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [2,943 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-dev-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [84.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc-bin amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [1,177 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libc6 amd64 2.15-0ubuntu10.15 [4,636 kB]
Fetched 8,840 kB in 1s (5,831 kB/s)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 71420 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6-dev 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6-dev_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6-dev ...
Preparing to replace libc-dev-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-dev-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-dev-bin ...
Preparing to replace libc-bin 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc-bin_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc-bin ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
(Reading database ... 71419 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 (using .../libc6_2.15-0ubuntu10.15_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6 ...
Setting up libc6 (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.15) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
git.checkout
1.19s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/romenigld/ticketee_two.git romenigld/ticketee_two
Cloning into 'romenigld/ticketee_two'...
remote: Counting objects: 925, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (351/351), done.
remote: Total 925 (delta 534), reused 913 (delta 526), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (925/925), 121.35 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (534/534), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd romenigld/ticketee_two
$ git checkout -qf 6803f83557e2cde143618cb3d3195686ceef8a3f
This job is running on container-based infrastructure, which does not allow use of 'sudo', setuid and setguid executables.
If you require sudo, add 'sudo: required' to your .travis.yml
See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/ for details.
rvm
29.02s$ rvm use 2.2.1 --install --binary --fuzzy
ruby-2.2.1 is not installed - installing.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/ubuntu/12.04/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.2.1 - #configure
ruby-2.2.1 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 21.5M  100 21.5M    0     0   136M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  138M
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.2.1 - #validate archive
ruby-2.2.1 - #extract
ruby-2.2.1 - #validate binary
ruby-2.2.1 - #setup
ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset created /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
ruby-2.2.1 - #importing gemset /home/travis/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems....................................
ruby-2.2.1 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.2.1 - #uninstalling gem rubygems-bundler-1.4.4.
ruby-2.2.1 - #gemset created /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
ruby-2.2.1 - #importing gemset /home/travis/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems....................
ruby-2.2.1 - #generating default wrappers........
chown: changing ownership of `/home/travis/.rvm/user/installs': Operation not permitted
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
$ export BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$PWD/Gemfile
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.26.10 (latest-minor) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.8.4
$ gem --version
2.4.6
before_install.1
0.00s$ export DISPLAY=:99.0
before_install.2
0.03s$ sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
Starting virtual X frame buffer: Xvfb.
install.bundler
104.99s$ bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching https://github.com/radar/searcher.git
Installing CFPropertyList 2.3.5
Installing rake 12.0.0
Installing i18n 0.8.0
Installing minitest 5.10.1
Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
Installing builder 3.2.3
Installing erubis 2.7.0
Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
Installing rack 1.6.5
Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Installing arel 6.0.4
Installing public_suffix 2.0.5
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Installing awesome_print 1.7.0
Installing bcrypt 3.1.11
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2
Installing json 1.8.6
Installing sass 3.4.23
Installing byebug 9.0.6
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Installing thor 0.19.1
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
Installing database_cleaner 1.5.3
Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
Installing diff-lcs 1.3
Installing excon 0.55.0
Installing formatador 0.2.5
Installing multi_json 1.12.1
Installing ipaddress 0.8.3
Installing inflecto 0.0.2
Installing net-ssh 4.1.0
Installing ffi 1.9.17
Installing pg 0.19.0
Using bundler 1.8.4
Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Installing rdoc 4.3.0
Installing rspec-support 3.2.2
Installing rubyzip 1.2.1
Installing tilt 2.0.6
Installing websocket 1.2.4
Installing puma 3.7.1
Installing fission 0.5.0
Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
Installing sqlite3 1.3.13
Installing rack-test 0.6.3
Installing warden 1.2.7
Installing mime-types 3.1
Installing addressable 2.5.0
Installing autoprefixer-rails 6.7.4
Installing uglifier 3.0.4
Installing nokogiri 1.7.0.1
Installing binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing sprockets 3.7.1
Installing fog-core 1.43.0
Installing childprocess 0.6.1
Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
Installing sdoc 0.4.2
Installing rspec-core 3.2.3
Installing rspec-expectations 3.2.1
Installing rspec-mocks 3.2.1
Installing activesupport 4.2.0
Installing mail 2.6.4
Installing launchy 2.4.3
Installing loofah 2.0.3
Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.7
Installing xpath 2.0.0
Installing fog-xml 0.1.2
Installing fog-json 1.0.2
Installing fog-local 0.3.1
Installing fog-vmfusion 0.1.0
Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing globalid 0.3.7
Installing activemodel 4.2.0
Installing selenium-webdriver 2.53.4
Installing factory_girl 4.8.0
Installing jbuilder 2.6.1
Installing pundit 0.3.0
Installing spring 2.0.1
Installing email_spec 1.6.0
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Installing fog-atmos 0.1.0
Installing capybara 2.12.1
Installing fog-ecloud 0.3.0
Installing fog-voxel 0.1.0
Installing fog-terremark 0.1.0
Installing fog-brightbox 0.11.0
Installing fog-powerdns 0.1.1
Installing fog-profitbricks 3.0.0
Installing fog-radosgw 0.0.5
Installing fog-riakcs 0.1.0
Installing fog-sakuracloud 1.7.5
Installing fog-serverlove 0.1.2
Installing fog-aws 0.13.0
Installing fog-softlayer 1.1.4
Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Installing fog-storm_on_demand 0.1.1
Installing activejob 4.2.0
Installing active_model_serializers 0.9.6
Installing carrierwave 0.10.0
Installing activerecord 4.2.0
Installing actionview 4.2.0
Using searcher 0.0.7 from https://github.com/radar/searcher.git (at master)
Installing actionpack 4.2.0
Installing actionmailer 4.2.0
Installing railties 4.2.0
Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Installing simple_form 3.1.1
Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
Installing responders 2.3.0
Installing factory_girl_rails 4.8.0
Installing font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.1
Installing jquery-rails 4.2.2
Installing rspec-rails 3.2.3
Installing rails 4.2.0
Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
Installing web-console 2.3.0
Installing devise 3.4.1
Installing fog 1.29.0
Bundle complete! 32 Gemfile dependencies, 120 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
47.23s$ bundle exec rspec
Running via Spring preloader in process 16341
.....................................................................................................................................
Finished in 37.49 seconds (files took 8.3 seconds to load)
133 examples, 0 failures
The command "bundle exec rspec" exited with 0.
dpl.0
Fetching: dpl-1.8.31.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-1.8.31
1 gem installed
dpl.1
Installing deploy dependencies
Fetching: multi_json-1.12.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.12.1
Fetching: excon-0.55.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed excon-0.55.0
Fetching: heroku-api-0.4.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed heroku-api-0.4.2
3 gems installed
Fetching: rendezvous-0.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.2
1 gem installed
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
authenticated as romenigld@gmail.com
checking for app 'ticketee-two'
found app 'ticketee-two'
Cleaning up git repository with `git stash --all`. If you need build artifacts for deployment, set `deploy.skip_cleanup: true`. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#Uploading-Files.
Ignoring path vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bundler/gems/searcher-c2975124e116/
Saved working directory and index state WIP on (no branch): 6803f83 Fleshed out tickets API with creating tickets and responses for error conditions
HEAD is now at 6803f83 Fleshed out tickets API with creating tickets and responses for error conditions
dpl.3
Deploying application
creating application archive
uploading application archive
triggering new deployment
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * thor (!= 0.19.2, != 0.19.3, != 0.19.4, = 0.19.1)
       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * thor (!= 0.19.2, != 0.19.3, != 0.19.4, = 0.19.1)
       Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * thor (!= 0.19.2, != 0.19.3, != 0.19.4, = 0.19.1)

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * thor (!= 0.19.2, != 0.19.3, != 0.19.4, = 0.19.1)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
Already up-to-date!
# HEAD detached at 6803f83
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Gemfile.lock
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   vendor/bundle/
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (9a3e736012166909408ff311798b4b90212a0775)
deploy failed, build exited with code 1
failed to deploy
```

And this errors in heroku logs:

```
2017-02-28T14:55:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user romenigld@gmail.com
2017-02-28T14:55:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
```

in my terminal I run in development:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I try to delete the Gemfile.lock then I do bundle install. and then I add and comment the git. The errors continues but in the Heroku logs shows me this:

```
2017-02-28T14:55:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user romenigld@gmail.com
2017-02-28T14:55:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2017-02-28T15:40:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user romenigld@gmail.com
2017-02-28T15:40:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2017-02-28T15:41:56.687079+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `git status` by user romenigld@gmail.com
```

My logs in development and production now has an error who never complain before. It was not rescuing anymore for shows projects who not exists by URL.

my production.log:

```
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.304131 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (0.9ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "schema_migrations" ("version" varchar NOT NULL) [0m
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.304626 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  select sqlite_version(*)
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.306274 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mCREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_schema_migrations" ON "schema_migrations" ("version")[0m
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.306855 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
I, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.309490 #3857]  INFO -- : Migrating to CreateProjects (20170118173125)
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.310099 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.311194 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  CREATE TABLE "projects" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar, "description" varchar, "created_at" datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at" datetime NOT NULL) 
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.316732 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES (?)[0m  [["version", "20170118173125"]]
D, [2017-01-19T12:16:25.317584 #3857] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  commit transaction
I, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.065690 #3931]  INFO -- : Started GET "/projects/not-here" for ::1 at 2017-01-19 12:20:59 +0100
I, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.070590 #3931]  INFO -- : Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
I, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.071233 #3931]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"not-here"}
D, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.088944 #3931] DEBUG -- :   [1m[36mProject Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 0]]
I, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.089393 #3931]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 18ms
F, [2017-01-19T12:20:59.090444 #3931] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=not-here):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:23:in `show'


I, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.855259 #3931]  INFO -- : Started GET "/projects/not-here" for ::1 at 2017-01-19 12:21:34 +0100
I, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.856238 #3931]  INFO -- : Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
I, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.856340 #3931]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"not-here"}
D, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.857160 #3931] DEBUG -- :   [1m[35mProject Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
I, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.857543 #3931]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms
F, [2017-01-19T12:21:34.858311 #3931] FATAL -- : 
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=not-here):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:23:in `show'
```

development.log file:

```
Started GET "/projects/not-here" for ::1 at 2017-01-19 12:14:09 +0100
  [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"not-here"}
  [1m[35mProject Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 18ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=not-here):
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:23:in `show'


  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (70.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (52.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/romenigld/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (121.7ms)
```

this occurs when I try to testing in my projects_controller_spec.rb file:

```
  it "handles a missing project correctly" do
    get :show, id: "not-here"

    expect(response).to redirect_to(projects_path)

    message = "The project you were looking for could not be found."
    expect(flash[:alert]).to eq message
  end
```

My projects_controller.rb

```
def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
        flash[:alert] = "The project you were looking for could not be found."
        redirect_to projects_path
    end
```

I don't understand during my tests all the time this works perfectly and now has these logs erros, if someone can help with this I will appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

Travis seems to be running on an older commit, maybe try to restart the build on https://travis-ci.org/romenigld/ticketee_two/builds/206285118 and see if it works.

**Edit:**

Since Heroku it is clearly running from an outdated commit from GitHub I would take a look at the deployment produce to find an error there. Was this the first commit that was pushed to Heroku?

If so, maybe you just need to turn on 'Automatic Deploys' on https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app/deploy/.

Comment: I restart the 'build on' on Travis CI and the error persists when try to deploy to heroku. thank's Harald Nordgren

Comment: Okay, good to know. Since Heroku it is clearly running from an outdated commit from GitHub I would take a look at the deployment produce to find an error there. Was this the first commit that was pushed to Heroku? If so, maybe you just need to turn on 'Automatic Deploys' on https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-app>/deploy/.

Comment: I put the thor gem in the version 0.19.0 and put this Automatic Deploys on the dashboard of Heroku setup and It works now. Thank you very much Harald Nordgren!! I'm searching about this error on heroku for vendor/bundle and it's recommended to put this on .gitignore file and i'm doing this now.

Comment: Nice be able to help. I edited my answer to include this information. Could you please accept and upvote the answer? :)